# Rails active record query basics

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm very new, and in the process of learning database stuff as well as Rails.  Right now I have the following statement:

```
def tournaments_played
  @tournaments_played = Tournament.count
end
```

With these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tournaments, through: :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
  has_many :tournaments

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :user
```

Obviously tournaments_played is returning a count of every record.  I only want the tournaments for that user.  I can paste in the scheme if needed!

Comment: Which user is "that" user? If you want the tournaments then you could do `@user.tournaments.count`, where `@user` has been assigned to a specific user. Also, you don't need `class_name: "User"` in the Profile model.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to give you a more specific answer, but you haven't indicated how you set up your Tournament model, so I can't give you actual code.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). You will find the answer to your question there.